# CacheImageNetwork didn't reload image

Tags: flutter, dart

I found issue of CacheImageNetwork
for example, API return status 404image url at the first time and we didn’t use cacheKey . In this case, CacheImageNetwork used url as key. After 4-5 seconds have elapsed, the API will return a status 200 along with an image URL. However, the cacheimage system recognizes the URL as the same as before and therefore retrieves the old cached image to display. This old cached image has a status of 400, causing it to be displayed incorrectly. I found this, we need to customize cacheKey as UniqueKey. but it’s not a good performance

So, How i fix this?
Certainly, here's an example of how to use a custom cacheKey based on the image URL and current timestamp with CacheImageNetwork:

```
import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imageUrl;

  const MyImage({Key? key, required this.imageUrl}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String cacheKey = '${imageUrl}_${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}';
    return CacheImageNetwork(
      imageUrl: imageUrl,
      cacheManager: DefaultCacheManager(key: cacheKey),
      placeholder: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      errorWidget: Icon(Icons.error),
    );
  }
}
```

In this example, we're generating a cacheKey by concatenating the image URL with the current timestamp in milliseconds since epoch. This helps ensure that the cacheKey is unique and changes with each request, which should prevent the old cached image with a 404 status code from being displayed.

Note that using DateTime.now() to generate the timestamp may not be the most precise approach, especially if you're requesting images rapidly. In that case, you may want to consider using a more precise timer or hash function to generate the cacheKey.

So, I want to know this is the good way to fix this?